# User Notice: escape: unsupported type: UTF-8 - returning unmodified string

Tags: error-handling, utf-8, prestashop, encode, prestashop-1.7

When i try to edit a blog post (click on edit):
i receive the following error:
**"User Notice: escape: unsupported type: UTF-8 - returning unmodified string"**
with the following code marked as the source of error in the smarty.config.inc.php:

```
return smarty_modifier_escape($string, $esc_type, $char_set, $double_encode);
```

I tried to change in classes/Tools.php, the function htmlentitiesUTF8():
htmlentities to htmlspecialchars like the following:

Before modification:

```
return htmlentities((string) $string, $type, 'utf-8');
```

after modification

```
return htmlspecialchars((string) $string, $type, 'utf-8');
```

Plus, i made sure in my Configuration->Database that the encodage is set to UTF-8,

And it is still not working ,
Any ideas ?

Thanks !

Comment: Do not include photos, and in any case never to external sites. You can copy and paste your code and your errors. We cannot work with photos: it makes nightmare to reproduce the error, to propose a solution, and to explain you what it is wrong (we cannot just copy paste core or errors). In addition, this is a reference site, so the images should be online as much as this question. External links cannot guarantee that.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi thank you for your corrections ,
I will edit my post so it matches that.

Comment: You have to post "tpl" file of your blog module

Answer (score 0):

`smartyEscape($string, $esc_type = 'html', $char_set = null, $double_encode = true)` function is using for escaping characters in html to prevent XSS attacks. It means, if someone will require to escape string for `UTF-8`, it will not be a problem if escape it for `html`. I implemented it in `~/config/smarty.config.inc.php` via adding a new condition.
Before:

```
function smartyEscape($string, $esc_type = 'html', $char_set = null, $double_encode = true)
{
    $escapeModifierFile = implode(
        DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,
        array(
            SMARTY_PLUGINS_DIR,
            'modifier.escape.php',
        )
    );
    require_once $escapeModifierFile;
    global $smarty;
    if (($esc_type === 'html' || $esc_type === 'htmlall') && $smarty->escape_html) {
        return $string;
    } else {
        return smarty_modifier_escape($string, $esc_type, $char_set, $double_encode);
    }
}
```

After:

```
function smartyEscape($string, $esc_type = 'html', $char_set = null, $double_encode = true)
{
    $escapeModifierFile = implode(
        DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,
        array(
            SMARTY_PLUGINS_DIR,
            'modifier.escape.php',
        )
    );
    require_once $escapeModifierFile;

    global $smarty;
    if (($esc_type === 'html' || $esc_type === 'htmlall') && $smarty->escape_html) {
        return $string;
    } else {
        if ('UTF-8' === $esc_type) {
            return smarty_modifier_escape($string, 'html', $char_set, $double_encode);
        }
        return smarty_modifier_escape($string, $esc_type, $char_set, $double_encode);
    }
}
```

I know, that this solution looks like a CRAP, but it's PrestaShop, and nothing can make it worse)